# How can I simplify $ \sum_{r=0}^{m-1}r^3\frac{\binom{m}{r}(m-r)!\begin{Bmatrix} n\\ m-r \end{Bmatrix}}{m^n}$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Let $N$ and $M$ be sets with $n$ and $m$ elements respectively with $n>m$. Randomly assign a function $f:N\to M$. Suppose that the probability of each element in $N$ being assigned to any element in $M$ is the same. And the assignments of different values in $M$ are independent. Define a random variable 
>   $$
> X:=m-|f(N)|,
> $$ i.e., the number of elements in $M$ which have no preimage. What is $E(X^3)$?

Using the Stirling numbers of the second kind, I can get:
$$
E(X^3)=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}r^3P(X=r)=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}r^3\frac{\binom{m}{r}(m-r)!\begin{Bmatrix}
n\\
m-r
\end{Bmatrix}}{m^n}.
$$

Here are my questions:

Can this formula be simplified further? Is there an alternative way to do this problem (such that we might get a simpler formula)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change of variable $r\rightarrow m-r$ gives 
$$
\sum_r (m-r)^3  \begin{Bmatrix}
n\\
r
\end{Bmatrix} (m)_r
$$
Here, the notation $(m)_r$ is for the product $m(m-1)\cdots (m-r+1)$.

We have 
$$(m-r)(m)_r = (m)_{r+1} = m (m-1)_r. $$
Thus 
$$(m-r)^2 (m)_r = (m-r-1+1)(m-r) (m)_r $$
$$= (m-r-1+1) (m)_{r+1} = (m)_{r+2} + (m)_{r+1}$$
Then
$$(m-r)^3 (m)_r = (m-r-2+2) (m-r)^2 (m)_r $$
$$=(m-r-2+2) ((m)_{r+2} + (m)_{r+1})$$
$$= (m)_{r+3} + 2(m)_{r+1}$$
$$= m(m-1)(m-2) (m-3)_r + 2 m (m-1)_r.$$

Note that there is a generating function formula for Stirling numbers:
$$
\sum_{r=0}^n \left\{\begin{matrix} n \\ r \end{matrix}\right\}
(x)_r = x^n.$$

Plugging in to the first formula, we obtain 
$$
\sum_r (m(m-1)(m-2) (m-3)_r + 2 m (m-1)_r) \left\{\begin{matrix} n \\ r \end{matrix}\right\}$$
$$=m(m-1)(m-2) (m-3)^n + 2m (m-1)^n.$$
Therefore, 
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^3] = \frac{m(m-1)(m-2) (m-3)^n + 2m (m-1)^n}{m^n}.$$